# why api key is creating without SH1 on android api console?

Tags: android

While creating map `api key` on api console earlier it shows package name and `SH1` option. But, now it is not showing.

What is the difference between key created by google and key created by package name?

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: are you talking about SHA1 created by google developer console and created by package name?

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new app on Google API console it generates an API key for you and you can generate your own key from the console, Any API key has to be restricted to be related to your app and track all API calls and requests made by your app through that key, Keys are restricted by adding the package name and SHA-1 fingerprint of your app which are unique to your app, You can ignore key restriction in debugging mode but if you decided to release your app key restriction will be required before publishing.